# Visa required for transit in Benin?

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas, benin

Going to Ivory Coast from Pakistan with Turkish airlines, I have a visa for Ivory Coast but do I need a transit visa for Benin? Also will I have to pay the departure fee while transiting?

Answer (score 2):

[Timatic](http://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/countryinfo.html) (Benin(Rep.) → Visa → TWOV) says

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> - Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents
>     required for the next destination.

Assuming you are travelling on flight TK557, the layover in Cadjehoun is so short that passengers continuing to Abidjan probably remain on the aircraft, which counts as  part of the international transit area. Even if you have to leave the aircraft for some reason, there is no reason for you to leave the transit area of the airport. In any case, you will not need a visa for Benin.